# Starting a new Activity with main activity layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm kinda new to android development and I'm trying to find the proper way of going about this, but in my `activity_main.xml` The toolbar `app_bar_parallax_fab` which was custom created by me is included within the xml of the activity_main which host the navbar.

So my initial thought is that I have to find a way to change the included xml. Which I have been researching for couple hours on how to change included file which I then found ViewFlipper but then looked into it deeper and read proper way to use viewflipper is when using the same activity.

I just need some assistance in how I should go about stating a new activity maybe throw some examples of something similar I am trying to accomplish. Or tell me that my thinking/interpretation is completely wrong!

This below is a snippet of activity_main.xml this is pretty much default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include android:id="@+id/mainContent" layout="@layout/app_bar_parallax_fab" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:text="@string/project_owner"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I then have an app bar called `account_app_bar.xml` which whitin includes `account_content.xml` because my custom app/toolbars change based on what activity/layout that is happening.

Below is the XML for custom toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="io.tarson.cryptovision.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_account_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/account_profile_banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/cafelights"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.4"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/appBarParallaxInclude"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/collapsing_account_toolbar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_edit"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb So for example going from dashboard/main activity to account Activity. But like I sated above I want to start a new activity but use the navbar like a traditional app

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes I just want to know the proper way to start a new activity but to continue to use the nav bar AKA nav drawer

Comment: Could you please provide the content of the @layout/app_bar_parallax_fab, so the circumstances will get somewhat more clear?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev added.

Comment: Thanks! However i'm afraid i couldn't get the problem correctly so far. Did you try to launch another activity with the `startActivity` method? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev It opens the the layout but the navigation drawer doesn't initialize

Comment: Ah, so you want to keep drawer present when opening an item from your drawer?

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev yes exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, you main objective is to keep drawer available when opening an item from it. For such purposes activities are not appropriate. Instead you need to use the same activity and manipulate with [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) within it.

Here is a short sample of how it may be implemented:

```
enum MenuItems {
    HOME,
    SETTINGS,
    FAQ,
}

private void openMenuItem(MenuItems selectedItem) {
    Fragment instance;
    switch (selectedItem) {
        case HOME:
            instance = HomeFragment.instantiate();
            break;
        case SETTINGS:
            instance = HomeFragment.instantiate();
            break;
        case FAQ:
            instance = HomeFragment.instantiate();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, instance);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The fragment_container should be a [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) type view (preferably [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)), that holds place for fragments (usually takes whole space within activity). In simplified case the whole layout with drawer may look something like that:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For more details you can refer to these docs:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html